# Why would @Html.Partial with absolute path find view yet razorViewEngine.FindView not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.net Core web application, I'm printing a partial view from within a view using:

```
@Html.Partial("~/some/absolute/path.cshtml")
```

yet attempting to procure the view as a string from controller, the view is null after

```
var viewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, "~/some/absolute/path.cshtml", false);
//viewResult.View will be null
```

Has anyone encountered this?  Rendering a view to string was slightly different prior to NET.Core, so I'm wondering if there's some particular project configuration I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use razorViewEngine.GetView instead of razorViewEngine.FindView.

Hope that helps!